# MVC Forms Authentication - can users share a logon and be logged in simultaneously?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have a MVC site that is very simple, and I do not want to bother creating a database and have a membership provider etc. to handle security. Security is just logging in, there is no user-specific role security required. I just don't want Joe Public to be accessing the pages.

I do want to make it accessible to clients, but without having to create new users in the system.

I want to use the web.config file to store some users ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0adyye.aspx)), and obviously changing this to add more people is ridiculous.

Can I create a single user in the web.config and give that logon to all clients? Will they be able to log in simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

You could put this attribute on the top of the controller you wish to have certain access:

```
[Authorize(Users="DOMAIN\\JoeBloggs")]
public class SomeController : Controller
```

Then just have one user in your web.config.

The issue with this is every controller will need this attribute, you could inherit from a base controller and put the authorize attribute on this.

Edit: Judging by your example you don't even need to specify the user in the attribute.  Just decorate it with `[Authorize]` and the forms login will sort the rest.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Unfortunately the clients are not no any domain, they are coming to the external website.

Comment: The domain was just an example, this can be any username you specify. So it works for forms and windows auth types.

Comment: And can multiple users log in simultaneously with the same credentials?

Comment: Absolutely fine, every user is handled as a separate state, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/12116510/537674

Comment: Let me do some work and run it through some tests, and I'll accept it. Have a +1 for now. Very, very useful thank you.